# When can a contrib module considered to be stable?

Tags: 8

Is there a clear definition of a module being stable in comparison with a release candidate? When can a stable version be released?

As an example, can't the [Read only mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTzMm.png) module considered stable?

[image]

Comment: It's up to you and your own risk assessment, really. Remember Drupal 7.31 was considered "stable", and we all know how that turned out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the docs.

[Release naming conventions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1015226)

> **rc**: A release candidate should only be created when the all critical bug type issues are reported fixed in the project's issue
>   queue. This tag should only be used when the developer believes that
>   the project is ready for use on a production site. **There is no
>   official best practice for how long a project should be a release
>   candidate before creating a official .0 release**, but it is suggested
>   that it should be out for at least a month with status set to "needs
>   review". If something (e.g. a new critical bug is reported) makes it
>   necessary to create a new release during this period, a new release
>   candidate should be created and this should remain for at least a
>   month with status set to "needs review".